# Regex to find a substring with a specific length that contains minimum occurrences of a specific characters

Tags: regex

Is there any regex to find a substring with a specific length that contains minimum number of a specific char occurrences?

For example I have a string such as: `AABABAAAAA` for this string we have a substring with length 5 that contains two B => `AABAB` so regex should find it.

But for the `AAAABAAAAB` there is not any substring with length of 5 that contains two B.

Suppose our string just contains A and B and we want to find substring with length of 5 that contains at least two B:

```
AAAABAAAAB -> Invalid
AAAAAAAABB -> Valid
AAAAAAAAAABAABAAAAAA -> Valid
AAAABAAAAAAABAAAAAAA -> Invalid
```

Comment: Can you double check the wording of your question? it sounds like you're just asking whether it contains BB and is at least 5 characters long?

Comment: Could you please show several different inputs and the corresponding expected outputs?

Comment: Surely you're specifying a *maximum* length for the substring, not a minimum. I.e. your "invalid" examples both contain substrings that are *at least* 5 characters long and contain two `B`s.

Comment: Thank you @Damien_The_Unbeliever ! I made mistake :( . Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brute force:

```
.B..B|B...B|..BB.|.B.B.|..B.B|BB...|B.B..|...BB|B..B.|.BB..
```

Well, I know that such regular expression is not parametrizable. On the other hand it's possible to obtain it programmatically (the example is in Python):

```
import itertools

def get_regex(char, charnum, strsize):
    chars = char * charnum + "." * (strsize - charnum)
    return "|".join("".join(x) for x in set(itertools.permutations(chars)))

print get_regex("B", 2, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
(?=[^B]{0,3}B[^B]{0,3}B).{5}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oM0uE3/2)

Comment: It does not work. The substring should contain at least two B. For string such as AAAABAAAAB the regex should not find any thing but your regex find!

Comment: Restricting the length of the lookahead seems to fix that; `(?=.*?B.{0,4}?B).{5}`.

Comment: Sorry had to go after my initial answer so couldn't respond in time. I have corrected my regex now. Please check. This is more efficient that brute force method and definitely more scalable. Imagine the regex if `B`'s have to be 20 char apart.